# How do I get input from a v-menu?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am new to Vue, and I am trying to figure out it it all works together. I want to create a drop-down menu so the user can select what type of user they are.

This is my template:

```
<v-menu offset-y>
    
    <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        
        <v-btn color="blue" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"> User Type </v-btn>
        
    </template>
    
    <v-list>
        
        <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" v-model="user_type">
            
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
        
        </v-list-item>
        
    </v-list>

</v-menu>
```

And this is my script:

```
data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      error: "",
      first_name: "",
      surname: "",
      items: [{ title: "Client" }, { title: "Freelancer" }],
      user_type: "",
    };
  }
```

Basically, I want the user to select whether they are a `Client` or a `Freelancer`, and I want to store that result in the `user_type` variable. I was able to store their other details using `v-model`'s like so:

```
<div class="first_name">
    <input 
        type="first_name"
        v-model="first_name"
        placeholder="First Name"
    />
</div>
```

I can't use a `v-model` with `v-menu` though, as it seems to return a boolean value for some reason. I have all of the basic functionality working, I just need to be able to access the user's choice in the drop-down menu. Is there something I am just not grasping here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `v-list-item-group` tag as parent of `v-list-item` you can use `v-model` on `v-list-item-group` and this will give the index of selected item.

```
<v-menu offset-y>
<template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
 <v-btn color="blue" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on"> User Type </v-btn>
</template>
<v-list>
 <v-list-item-group v-model="user_type">
   <v-list-item v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
     <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
   </v-list-item>
</v-list>
</v-menu>
```

Comment: I can work with the index, this is really helpful, thanks.